# how to Change Configuration of mondrian about join Table

Tags: performance, mdx, query-performance, mondrian

I have a query like below :

```
with member 
  [Measures].[ASD] as 
    'Count(
       Filter(
         [DId].[DId].Members
         , [Measures].[X] >=2000000000
       )
     )'
select
  [Branch].[City].Members on axis(0),
  [Measures].[ASD] on axis(1)
from [D];
```

For `mondrian` it takes a lot of time to run - about 40s.
This is because it is querying for each city like below:

```
[[DId].[DId]]: executing sql [select "D"."D_Id" as "c0" from "XXX"."D" "DId", "XXX"."BRANCH" "BRANCH" where "D"."FD_BRANCH" = "BRANCH"."BRANCH_ID" and "BRANCH"."CITY_ID" = 111 group by "D"."D_Id" having (sum("D"."X") >= 2000000000) order by "D"."D_Id" ASC NULLS LAST]
```

If you write in SQL language and run it in for example oracle it's take just 1s.
I wanna know Is there any configuration in `mondrian` to say don't query like this and query in formal way?

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(FILTER` should be avoided.

This hopefully runs quicker:

```
with member 
  [Measures].[ASD] as 
    'Sum(
       [DId].[DId], //<<maybe this should read [DId].[DId].[DId]? 
       Iif([Measures].[X] >=2000000000,1,NULL)
     )'
select
  [Branch].[City].Members on axis(0),
  [Measures].[ASD] on axis(1)
from [D];
```

Explained here by Mosha: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/11/22/optimizing-count-filter-expressions-in-mdx.aspx

Comment: Thnak you for answering ... but when i did it the below query execute:select "D"."D_ID" as "c0" from "XXX"."D" "D" group by "D"."D_ID" order by "D"."D_ID" ASC NULLS LAST . that took a lot of time and finally my memory crashed!! so unfortunately i couldn't use this solution :(

Comment: Yes It does, I posted it in before cmt